# Paypal Digital Express Goods Checkout Pop-up Windows

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

I am having a problem with the Paypal digital goods express checkout code.  The PayPal script calls for pop-up windows to be opened for a user to enter their information.  Sometimes for a simple login, other times for creating a new account.

The pop-up window is supposed to re-direct the user once the data has been entered.  However, all it does is hang-up and freeze, or re-directs to a PayPal window and freezes.

I have disabled many of the pop-ups and everything works great, I can get the data into my DB and I can re-direct to pages on my site.

But, there are areas where the PayPal windows pop-up and I can't find where to disable the pop-up windows and force the code into a browser window.

Any help is suggested.  Been at this for over a week with PayPal and can't seem to find the answer.

Thanks,

Grant

Comment: We deployed some code fixes today. Can you confirm whether you are still having these issues?

Comment: I have the same problem. Many users paypal page hangs after making express checkout or cannot pay at all